# Encounter segmentation fault with recursive method

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

```
class Apple
{
 public:
   Apple func(int depth) const;
 private:
   int size = 0; // size of data array  
   double *data = nullptr;
}

Apple::func(int depth) const
{
  Apple new_apple;

  '''
  some calculations
  '''

  if(depth>1)
  {
    return new_apple.func(depth-1);
  }else
  {
    return new_apple;
  }
}
```

In the method func(), I create a new Apple object, and perform some calculations based on the data stored in the original Apple object. The terminal gives out

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I believe there is something wrong with the memory as I get the following message from valgrind.

```
==4787== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4787==     in use at exit: 5,994 bytes in 63 blocks
==4787==   total heap usage: 1,059 allocs, 996 frees, 146,564 bytes allocated
==4787== 
==4787== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4787==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4787==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4787==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4787==    still reachable: 5,994 bytes in 63 blocks
==4787==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==4787==                         newarray           : 1,080 bytes in 3 blocks
==4787==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Valgrind tracks to the overloaded operator= of the class Apple. There is only one member (I name it data here) involves dynamic memory, so I only show the part related to it here. Here's how operator= is implemented:

```
Apple& Apple::operator=(const Apple &obj)
{
  if(this!=&obj)
  {
    if(this->data)
    {
      delete[] this->data;
    }
    this->size = obj.size;
    this->data = new double[this->size];
    for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
    {
      this->data[i] = obj.data[i];
    }
  }
  return *this
}
```

=========================================================================

The method func() works fine if I do not add the recursive component. And I have also checked with valgrind, there is no problem with the memory of the calculation part.

```
Apple::func(int depth) const
{
  Apple new_apple;

  '''
  some calculations
  '''
  return new_apple; // works fine
}
```

The same segmentation fault occurs even when I call the func(int depth) with depth = 1.

```
Apple::func(int depth) const
{
  Apple new_apple;

  '''
  some calculations
  '''

  if(depth>1)
  {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    return new_apple.func(depth-1);
  }else
  {
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    return new_apple;
  }
}
```

Neither "1" or "2" is printed out when I call func(1).

=========================================================================
Debugging message from gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Apple::operator= (this=0x0, T=...) at src/xxxx.cpp:1011
1011          if(this->data)
```

=========================================================================
**Update**: (Added a sample code that causes the error)

I have added a sample code that is much closer to the structure of my real code.

**Sample code:**

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f7e50e4ebabf717

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Apple
{
public:
  Apple();
  ~Apple();
  Apple(const Apple &obj);
  void alloc(int size);
private:
  double *data = nullptr;
  int size = 0;
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////
class Basket
{
public:
  Basket();
  ~Basket();
  Basket(const Basket &obj);
  void alloc(int size1, int size2);
  Basket func(int depth);
private:
  Apple *data = nullptr;
  int size;
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////
Apple::Apple(){}
Apple::~Apple()
{
  if(this->data)
  {
    delete[] this->data;
  }
}
Apple::Apple(const Apple &obj)
{
  if(this->data)
  {
    delete[] this->data;
  }
  this->size = obj.size;
  this->data = new double[this->size];
  for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
  {
    this->data[i] = obj.data[i];
  }
}
void Apple::alloc(int size)
{
  this->size = size;
  if(this->data)
  {
    delete[] this->data;
  }
  this->data = new double[size];
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Basket::Basket(){}
Basket::~Basket()
{
  if(this->data)
  {
     delete[] this->data;
  }
}
Basket::Basket(const Basket &obj)
{
  this->size = obj.size;
  // This is the missing piece
  /*
  if(this->data)
  {
      delete[] this->data;
  }
  this->data = new Apple[this->size];
  */
  for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
  {
    this->data[i] = obj.data[i];
  }
}
void Basket::alloc(int size1, int size2)
{
  if(this->data)
  {
    delete[] this->data;
  }
  this->size = size1;
  this->data = new Apple[this->size];
  for(int i=0; i<size1; i++)
  {
    this->data[i].alloc(size2);
  }
}
Basket Basket::func(int depth)
{
  Basket new_basket;
  new_basket.alloc(5,5);
  if(depth>1)
  {
    cout << 1 << endl;
    return new_basket.func(depth-1);
  }else
  {
    cout << 2 << endl;
    return new_basket;
  }
}
int main()
{
  Basket basket;
  Basket new_basket = basket.func(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does debugging tell you?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use 'std::vector' to store the 'data' array?

Comment: @CinCout I have added the debugging message, it also trackes to the operator=.

Comment: @AchimGuetlein Actually no. I will try whether the problem can be  avoided by using std::vector. Pointer is so difficult to handle btw.

Comment: I've made a [MCVE] based on the code you provided, and it does not crash. Therefore, the problem must be in code you haven't shown us. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d9dcccea930a5ba

Comment: The calculation is very lengthy and complicated. Please give me some time to see whether I can reproduce the error with minimal code.

Comment: Are you using lambda functions in your calculations?

Comment: I have added the more complete sample code. The error is caused by the improper implementation of copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Resolved.**

The error is caused by the **improper implementation of copy constructor of class Basket**.

**My original copy constructor:**

```
Basket::Basket(const Basket &obj)
{
  this->size = obj.size;
  for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
  {
    this->data[i] = obj.data[i];
  }
}
```

**The correct copy constructor:**

```
Basket::Basket(const Basket &obj)
{
  this->size = obj.size;
  if(this->data)
  {
      delete[] this->data;
  }
  this->data = new Apple[this->size];
  for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
  {
    this->data[i] = obj.data[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using address sanitizer (to teach how to fish and not giving a fish):

```
$ clang++ -Wall -std=c++14 soApple.cpp -o soApple -fsanitize=address -g
$ ./soApple 
1
2
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==25955==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7fff6cdb1fd0 bp 0x7ffeea7d7e80 sp 0x7ffeea7d7e80 T0)
==25955==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
==25955==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7fff6cdb1fcf in _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell (libsystem_platform.dylib:x86_64+0x4fcf)
    #1 0x10547d58f in __asan_memcpy (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x4f58f)
    #2 0x105428f4c in Basket::Basket(Basket const&) soApple.cpp:72
    #3 0x105428f8c in Basket::Basket(Basket const&) soApple.cpp:68
    #4 0x10542957d in Basket::func(int) soApple.cpp:99
    #5 0x1054294e4 in Basket::func(int) soApple.cpp:95
    #6 0x105429b52 in main soApple.cpp:105
    #7 0x7fff6caa0014 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1014)

==25955==Register values:
rax = 0x0000000000000000  rbx = 0x000000010620e880  rcx = 0x00006040000004d0  rdx = 0x0000000000000004  
rdi = 0x0000000000000000  rsi = 0x0000608000000128  rbp = 0x00007ffeea7d7e80  rsp = 0x00007ffeea7d7e80  
 r8 = 0x0000000500006040   r9 = 0x00000001064297f0  r10 = 0x000000010ec703e0  r11 = 0xffff9f7ffffffed8  
r12 = 0x000000000000000c  r13 = 0x0000000000000000  r14 = 0x0000608000000128  r15 = 0x0000000000000000  
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (libsystem_platform.dylib:x86_64+0x4fcf) in _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell
==25955==ABORTING
Abort trap: 6
```

When inspecting line 72 in `soApple.cpp` it point to:

```
Basket::Basket(const Basket &obj)
{
  this->size = obj.size;
  for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
  {
    this->data[i] = obj.data[i]; <-- here is a crash
  }
}
```

Basically `this->data` is not set/allocated.
Best way to fix it is to use `std::vector` then this template will take responsibility for memory management and you r code will be simpler more readable and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. My real code is even more complicated than the sample code above. Sometimes I just forget to allocate memory when the size of my code grows large. I wouldn't notice it if I wasn't going to write a more complete sample code.